# Multiple conditions in while loop using &&

Tags: c++, while-loop

**What works:**

```
ifstream in("CallHello.cpp");
while(in >> s) {
    if(s=="cout")
        count++;
}
cout<<"Number of words : "<<count<<endl;
```

Output is 1 here which is correct.

**What doesn't work**

```
ifstream in("CallHello.cpp");
while(in >> s && s == "cout") {
    count++;
}
cout<<"Number of words : "<<count<<endl;
```

Output is 0, for the above which is wrong.

Why adding another condition in the while using && gives the wrong output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the first condition will continue looping while `in` has something to put on `s`, the second condition where you use `while(in >> s && s == "cout")` will only work if the first time you retrieve a value for `s` has a string of  `"cout"` then it will run the block, therefore, your first value in `s` is not also `"cout"` the first time, so it just never loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason why:

```
string s;
int count = 0;
while (in >> s && s == "cout") { // Ops: s == ""
    ++count;                     // while condition is false!
}                                // loop is skipped!

cout<<"Number of words : "<<count<<endl; // count was never incremented
                                         // Output is 0
```